# Create wrapped PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, annotations, spring-el

I'm trying to create a wrapped annotation but i don't know it is possible this, anybody do this before?

```java
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@PreAuthorize("@auth.hasAccess(token, id)")
public @interface HasAdminRole {
    String token();
    String id();
}
```

I expect that SpEL use the token and id values of @interface to call 'hasAccess' but don't do nothing.